# IE Text size increase cause overlap in HTML elements. How do i fix it?

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm running into [this problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDO1z.jpg) Whenever a user increased text size in IE9 by going to View->Text. I'm not a web designer so my knowledge of CSS is limited and I inhered this project which look quite messy to me.

Here is the aspx page of the markup:

```
 <body leftMargin="0" topMargin="0" MS_POSITIONING="GridLayout">
    <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
        <CC1:FOCUSMANAGER id="FocusManager1" runat="server" DefaultColor="blue</cc1:FocusManager"></CC1:FOCUSMANAGER>
        <div style="Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 2px; VISIBILITY: visible; WIDTH: 358px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 16px; HEIGHT: 212px">
            <uc1:itemsearch id="ItemSearch" runat="server"></uc1:itemsearch>
        </div>
        <div style="Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 380px; VISIBILITY: visible; WIDTH: 316px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 16px; HEIGHT: 200px">
            <uc1:membersearch id="MemberSearch" runat="server"></uc1:membersearch>
        </div>
        <div style="Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 2px; VISIBILITY: visible; WIDTH: 690px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 228px; HEIGHT: 550px"
            id="DIV1" runat="server"><uc1:itemgrid id="ItemGrid" runat="server"></uc1:itemgrid></div>
        <div style="Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 2px; VISIBILITY: visible; WIDTH: 690px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 252px; HEIGHT: 513px"
            id="DIV2" runat="server"><uc1:acctlookupform id="AcctLookupForm" runat="server"></uc1:acctlookupform></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is behaving as expected.  When increasing text size, it does NOT increase the size of your containers because those are specified in `px`.

Option 1: Use a version of IE that has a `magnify` which also enlarges containers.  Not being an IE user I can't give any more help than that.

Option 2: Specify sizes either in `em` or `%`, which for most things should be the only units of measure used.  Images may be sized in `px`.

Just as a note:  This is an HTML question, so it is better to show the rendered HTML, rather than the script that generates it.